# How can I suppress loading Facebook Like Box until scroll on Wordpress theme?

Tags: jquery, facebook, wordpress, lazy-loading, facebook-likebox

Using the most recent Facebook Likebox code...

After the body opening tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Near the footer:

```
<div class="prefooter-node" id="facebook-like-box">
      <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true">
      </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can lazy load the likebox until the user scrolls into the region.  I have looked at other post, but I haven't found some kind of solution for Wrodpress.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at WPSocialite; it uses the SocialiteJS plugin http://www.socialitejs.com so the loading process occurs on hover or on page scroll.

WPSocialite: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsocialite/

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for just some jquery solution, but this works!

Comment: Actually, this is only for sharing, and has nothing to do with Facebook Like Box.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late for the asker but sharing the answer here, if someone else needs it:

You would need JQuery to be loaded on the web page before this script is executed.

```
<script>
var fb_loaded = false;//To track loading only once on a page.

function loadFaceBook(){
var fb_div = $("#facebookHolder");

var top = fb_div.offset().top;

if ( !fb_loaded && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > top ) 
{
    fb_loaded = true;

    $('#facebookHolder').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>'); 
    $('#facebookHolder').append('YOUR_FB_PAGE_ID' width="300" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false">'); //Change RED colored name to your Facebook page address.
jQuery.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', function() { 
      FB.init({status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true}); 
   }); 
 } 
} 

/*AM22 Facebook Lazy load - START*/

$(function () { 
    var fb_div = $("#facebookHolder"); 

    if (fb_div.size() > 0) { 
    $(window).scroll(loadFaceBook); 
    } 
}); 
/*AM22 Facebook lazy load - END*/ 
</script>
```

And then add this DIV tag in the HTML or Wordpress PHP file:

```
<div id="facebookHolder"></div>
```

Reference:
http://www.am22tech.com/load-facebook-like-box-on-scroll-asynchronously/